# Python: Functions is not running when called from a menu

Tags: python, function, menu

I'm currently working on an small banking application in python. I created functions that opens a txt file. I tested the function on its own so I know it works, however when implemented alongside the menu it seems not to work.

```
def parse_in():
    with open('bank.txt', 'r') as details:
        lines = details.read().splitlines()

    return lines
```

Later on I have a simple menu with few options but here I will only show the one I'm having issues with.

```
def menu():
    print("Please selected one of the options" + "\n\t1: Open account"



while True:
    try:
        selection = int(input("Please enter your choice: "))
        if selection == 1:
            open_account(details)
        else:
            break
    except:
        print("Please enter number 1-6")
```

if 1 is selected an open account should be ran

```
def open_account(details):
    print("Welcome to your new account")
    new_account_number = randint(000000, 999999)
    while True:
        try:
            new_account_balance = float(input("Enter your sum of money: "))
            if new_account_balance < 0:
                print("please enter positive value")
            else:
                break
        except:
            print("Please Enter Number Only")
    while True:
        new_account_name = input("Enter your name: ")
        if "  " in new_account_name:
            print("Please enter your full name")
        else:
            break

    details.append(new_account_number)
    details.append(new_account_balance)
    details.append(new_account_name)
```

After the information was imputed the idea is that they're suppose to save to the same file using a function.

```
def parse_out(details):
    with open('bank.txt', 'w') as file:
        for i in details:
            file.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

and everything is ran in main function

```
def main():
    details = parse_in()
    welcome()
    menu()
    parse_out(details)
```

When I press 1 the open account function seems not be running instead, the menu loops back to choosing one of the options. I'n not really sure why it does that as it seems it should run and take information from user fallowed by saving the info to file.

Comment: Could you [edit] your code so it is runnable? With the indentation as given this is not valid Python code.

Comment: Could you edit your code , like in the menu function, it doesnt seem to be complete. it needs to have an except

Comment: Thanks for info, fixed it and added the except

Comment: Your issue seems to be , in menu you are not passing details as an argument. If you pass it as an argument in the function call and the definition, it should solve your current predicament.

Comment: Keep your `try: ... except: ...` blocks small and specify the error you want to catch. This way the Interpreter could tell you the Error that occured.